# Populate second dropdown depending upon selected value in first dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I need to populate second combo by executing Mysql query having a parameter which is selected from first combo in my jsp page. I think AJAX will work but I don't find the idea and correct syntax for AJAX for populating second combo by executing query.

Thanks in advance.

Now, I found correct syntax ti write an Ajax call as below:

```
 function newXMLHttpRequest()
     { 
        var req = null; 
        try {  
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari 
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer 
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


    return req;
}

 function updateCombo()
{
    var req = newXMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() 
     {
       if(req.readyState == 4)
       {
         if(req.status == 200)
         {
              var xmlDoc=req.responseXML;
          //Fill your combo with data
         } 
         else 
         {          

         } 
       } 
      };
    req.open("GET","myURL", false ); 
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send();
    return status;
}
```

Thanks All.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? I hope you don't expect us writing the code for you, do you?

Comment: No way. I tried to write an AJAX based on my jsp. I called a javascript function on onchange of first dropdown and write the below ajax:  
var selectedGroup = document.getElementById("groupList").value;
$.getJSON('abc.jsp?groupVal='+ selectedGroup,function(data){
        alert(groupVal);
        });  where abc.jsp is the same jsp where both the dropdowns have been created.But the alert box dint work. I think AJAX syntex is not proper. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: posting some of your code will be nice. So other can point what you have done wrong.

Comment: Please mention the above code in the question , this will improve the hit rate of your question and attract more answers.

Comment: How to Edit the question? Sorry I am new to this!!